# Image HEIGHT are not scaling in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, image-scaling

Well I am using this CSS code to scale a image automatically:

```
.img-responsive {

    display: block;

    max-width: 100%;

    height: auto;

    width: 450px;

 }
```

It works okay in most browsers. But in IE 8 the HEIGHT do not scale!

I have done a lot of search but could not find any solution?

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image needs a container around it. This question was already answered here:

[max-width on <img> tag not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915219/max-width-on-img-tag-not-working-in-ie8)